# How to remove floating code section from Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

For some reason a weird floating code section started to appear sometimes inside the Android Studio code window (selected in red):

[image]

Has anyone encountered this thing? Knows what it is? And how do I get rid of it?

Comment: Try pressing Esc key.

Comment: @FaizanHaidarKhan I did, it does not remove this window.

Comment: Experiencing the same problem with my project - floating sections appear when a particular file goes 'off screen'. Very frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you hover over a collapsed code lines, it shows what's inside. I think it disappears once you move the mouse pointer away from that area.

Comment: You are right, similar window popups when you hover over a collapsed code section. But in my case this wasn't a collapsed code. In my case for some reason Android Studio select a peace of code in class and show this floating window constantly until the selected code in class appears in the main code window.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting Android Studio worked for me. Not sure of a quicker fix.